# TypeOrm OneToMany/ManyToOne relations with PostgresSQL

Tags: typeorm

In My nestJs project, my using TypeOrm to create and manage my pg data. I have two entities User $ Tasks with OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship between them (respectively), i want to create a new task and save it to an existing user without re-creating it (user) again.
here is the code

```js
************ to create new task ************************************
async createTask(parms:CreateTaskDto):Promise<Task>{
        const {username}= parms;
        const newTask = this.taskRepo.create(parms);
        const user = await this.userRepo.findOne({name:username});
            user.tasks = Promise.resolve([newTask]);
            await this.userRepo.save(user);
        return newTask;
    }
********************************************************************
```

Note: For the first insertion it works fine but if i re-insert a new task, i lose the previous values of userTd field.
[Task db table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esIuF.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that i was trying to save the new task using the user repository and that was the issue, i should have done this:

```js
    async createTask(parms:CreateTaskDto):Promise<Task>{
            const {id}= parms;
            const task = this.taskRepo.create(parms);
            const user = await this.userRepo.findOne(id);
            task.user = user;
            return this.taskRepo.save(task);
        }
```

and it is logic cause the userId is a foreign key in the tasks table (due to ManyToOne decorator ).